# No dashboard/terminal/sidebar displayed in ubuntu 14.04 after removing python3.4

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, ubuntu-14.04, gnome

**Problem summary:** No dashboard/terminal/sidebar displayed in Ubuntu 14.04 after uninstalling Python3.4

**How it happened:** I was working on a project which requires Python3.5 . My Ubuntu 14.04.5 had already Python3.4 installed in it. After installing Python3.5, I removed Python3.4 as I was facing some problem.

While uninstalling Python3.4(using 'sudo apt-get remove python3.4'), I realized that I have made a mistake by uninstalling it, as it caused to remove many other packages related to display/software updates/other display related packages. 
I reinstalled the Python3.4 package and rebooted the system. But then I found that the desktop of my system is not coming properly. **There is no dashboard/sidebar/terminal/settings option visible. Even ctr+alt+T not working.**

**Tried Solution:** I installed **python3.4/ubuntu-desktop/software-center** packages there(using ctr+alt+F1) but they did not improve the situation. I still don't understand which packages I need to install in order to fix this. I appreciate any help for it.

Answer (score 1):

I landed up in the same situation, doing the same thing as you. To make matters worse (may be) I even tried to uninstall Python2. My thinking was, if I have Python3, why do I need 2?

Anyway, I was scrambling to find a fix, when I came across your query, which gave me an idea. I hit Ctrl+Alt+F1, and at the command prompt issued this command:

```
sudo apt-get install unity
```

That fixed the issue.

I realize you may have already resolved the issue, but I figured this might help others.